# Is there a UI component kit for react-native like ionic framework?

Tags: ionic-framework, react-native

I am playing around with a small app in react-native and I was wondering if there is a ready to use set of components that look like iOS's components. Somewhat like ionic-framework provides for Angular? Or am I missing something that is already in react-native that I can use?

To clarify I am referring to things like:

[image: bar]

[image: items with icons]

[image: slider toggle]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of the built in UI components are going to look native to begin with, for example [Switch](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/switch.html#content) looks like the native switch component for each platform, [ActivityIndicatorIOS](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/activityindicatorios.html#content) is natively styled, [PickerIOS](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/pickerios.html#content)  has a native design, etc etc...

Also, there are a couple of frameworks that are out there that I am aware of, both being designed around material design:

[Material React Native](http://mrn.js.org/) and [React Native Material Kit](https://github.com/xinthink/react-native-material-kit)

Comment: Thanks, I will give switches a try later :). Those UI kits look interesting for android applications.

Comment: MRN hasn't developed in over a year, and doesn't officially support iOS

Answer (score 23):

Here is a list of the ones I've found so far, I will keep updating it as a reference:

[Shoutem](http://shoutem.github.io/docs/ui-toolkit/introduction)

[React Native Material Kit](http://www.xinthink.com/react-native-material-kit/)

[Native Base](https://nativebase.io/)

[React Native Elements](https://github.com/react-native-training/react-native-elements)

[Kitten Tricks](https://github.com/akveo/kittenTricks)

[React Native Material Design](https://github.com/react-native-material-design/react-native-material-design)

[Teaset](https://github.com/rilyu/teaset)

[Nachos UI](https://avocode.com/nachos-ui/)

[Panza](https://github.com/panza-org/panza)

[React Native UI Kit](https://github.com/andyfen/react-native-uikit)

[Ignite](https://infinite.red/ignite)

[Wix Components](https://github.com/wix/react-native-ui-lib)

[MRN](http://mrn.js.org)

[APEX UI](https://github.com/glinjy/react-native-apex-ui)

[React Native Komect UIKit](https://github.com/fengshanjian/react-native-komect-uikit)

[Ant Design Mobile](https://mobile.ant.design/)

[React-Virgin](https://github.com/Trixieapp/react-virgin)

Answer (score 8):

More recently there's [NativeBase](http://nativebase.io/) and [Shoutem](http://shoutem.github.io/), both of which seem quite comprehensive.

Update: There's now [Material-UI](https://github.com/xotahal/react-native-material-ui) that looks pretty good (I'm not sure if it's the same as the web-based Material UI).

Comment: Those both look like great places to get started on new projects. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Another on looks promising to me if you want to keep consistency between web and native app [Ant Design Mobile](https://mobile.ant.design/) from [Ant Design](https://ant.design/)